# I want to give a dynamic width to CSS property's value in React. How can I achieve that

Tags: css, reactjs

const silderValue = averageRound * 20;

{silderValue}%

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way :

```
<div style={{width:`${silderValue}%`}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  // Calculate the width dynamically using JavaScript
  const width = 100;

  return (
    <div style={{ width: width }}>
      This element has a dynamic width.
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).